# Updating cocoapod files with 'GoldenFleece' locking Target Supported Files in CornerStone

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, cocoapods, cornerstone

I took code from Cornerstone.and updated podileby adding 'GoldenFleece' to the file and install pod again.
After successfully installed the pod Target Support files added few files. 
But Target Support Files are not showing in Cornerstone. It is showing as ~ symbol folder which is unable to commit changes.